# How to find out the number of received packets from each sender

Tags: omnet++, inet

In OMNET++ with INET framework, I want to find out how many packets are received from each sending node.I found the below code. Can anyone tell me what is function of "it->second++" command in below code?

```
std::map<L3Address, uint64_t> recPkt;
auto it = recPkt.find(senderAddr);
if (it == recPkt.end())
    recPkt[senderAddr] = 1;
else
    it->second++;
```

Also, can anyone suggest how to display the number of received packets per node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`it` is an iterator to an element of `std::map`. Iterator is something like a pointer. `it` points to a pair: `<L3Address, uint64_t>`. Probably the address of sender is the first element of this pair, and the second one is the number of received packets.
The first element of this pair may be obtained using `it->first` while the second  via `it->second`.
Operation `recPkt.find(senderAddr)` checks whether `recPkt` contains an entry with the address `senderAddr`:

- if not, `it` points to `recPkt.end()`, then a new entry is created and 1 is set as value (because first packet has been just received),
- if entry for `senderAddr` already exists, the second value of this element (counter) is incremented using `it->second++`

To show current value of received packets to internal log window one may use:

```
for (auto it : recPkt) {
   EV << "From address " << it.first << " received " << it.second << " packets." << std::endl;   
}
```

However, the better way is to write these values to statistics. The best place for it is a `finish()` method of your module:

```
void YourModule::finish() {
   // ..
   for (auto it : recPkt) {
      std::string name = "Received packet from ";
      name += it.first.str(); // address
      recordScalar(name, it.second);  
    } 
}
```

Reference: [C++ Reference, std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/)

**EDIT**

One more thing. The declaration of `recPkt` i.e. line:

```
std::map<L3Address, uint64_t> recPkt;
```

must be in your class. `recPkt` cannot be declared just before use.

Comment: Did you actually mean "recPkt" while you wrote "recv" ? You mentioned, for "if (it == recPkt.end())" command, 1 is set as value because first packet has been just received. Does it mean first packet from the node with the address "senderAddr" received? Another thing is, if i want display this in log window, where I need to write the code? Is it in .cc file under finish()? Thanks  a lot.

Comment: Jerzy, also please suggest me where to write the map creating codes that I mentioned in my post.

Comment: It was typo, I have corrected my answer. After `auto it = recPkt.find(senderAddr);` condition `it == recPkt.end()` means that there is no this address in `recPak`, so the first packet from `senderAddr` is now received. You may display anything to log window in any place in your code. The most appropriate place to display number of received packet is just after the code where the `recPkt` is modified.

Comment: _where to write the map creating codes that I mentioned in my post_ - the code from your question should be inserted just after receiving a packet, e.g. in `hadleMessage()` or in the method derived from `handleMessage()`.

Comment: I wrote the code from my question followed by log window display part under handleMessage() and got the error: inet/linklayer/xmac/XMac.cc:522:39: error: ‘senderAddr’ was not declared in this scope.  Would you suggest how to get ride of this error?

Comment: It is probably another issue so I suggest adding a new question with [mcve] of your problem.

Comment: I opened a new question. Thank you.

Comment: I have added important clue to my answer.

Comment: Thank you Jerzy. Would you give an example? I did not understand it.

Comment: I would like to stress that `recPkt` must be declared inside definition of class. If you define it like in your question, every time the new instance of `recPkt` will be created.